# Read a different .txt depending on what button is pressed in previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, text, textview, extras

I'm trying to read a different .txt file (in a raw folder) in a second activity TextView depending on what button is pressed in `MainActivity` (the previous activity), but it doesn't work. I'm using the `.putextras` method and here is my code of the **MainActivity**:

```
    ImageButton but1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            int1.putExtra("Thistext", "textnumberone");
            startActivity(int1);


            finish();



        }
    });

    ImageButton but2(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            int2.putExtra("Thistext", "textnumbertwo");
            startActivity(int2);


            finish();



        }
    });
```

Here is my code of the SecondActivity with the Bundle..

```
    Bundle extradata = getIntent().getExtras();


    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firsttextView);
    vitautori.setText(extradata.getString("Thistext"));

    if (extradata.equals("textnumberone")) {

        String texttxt = "";
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {

            while ((texttxt = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                sbuffer.append(texttxt + "n");

            }

            tv.setText(sbuffer);
            is.close();


        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently comparing the *Bundle* data to a string in

> if (extradata.equals("textnumberone"))

This will not work, you have to extract the *String* data first. Try this:

```
Bundle extradata = getIntent().getExtras();
String textString = extradata.getString("Thistext");
if (textString.equals("textnumberone")) {
```

One other thing: 
You set the *String* from the *Bundle* to a (I suppose) *TextView* in

> vitautori.setText(extradata.getString("Thistext"));

but I don't see the initialization of `vitautori` anywhere. So make sure the it is initialized or this will crash.

Comment: Thank you very much Bmuig, it works now. I gave you a thumb up.

Comment: You are very welcome. If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the `Intent` (both places, of course), I suggest you try to set the type to text:

```
int1.setType("text/plain");
```

See if this helps.